# Java Selenium: how to print out error and catch exception from executing javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, exception, webdriver

The element is visible and clickable, but clicking the element is not working. Trying to catch exception and show the error message.

```
    try {
        element.click();
    } catch (WebDriverException e) {
        // how to print out error? also tried: System.out.println(...)
        e.printStackTrace();
       
        // how to catch exception/error from javascript?
       ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
             "arguments[0].click()", element);
    }
```

Questions:

1. how to print out exception? Could not find the stacktrace in console(windows) or test report html.
2. how to catch exception/error from executing javascript?

Comment: Try looking at [Exception handling in Selenium Webdriver](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/exceptions-in-selenium-webdriver) and [Selenium 2/Webdriver Javascript exception handling:  error message is null most of the time(Java API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559848/selenium-2-webdriver-javascript-exception-handling-error-message-is-null-most-o).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.